# Stackdriver debugger: How to find VERSION information for projects deployed outside GKE and App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java
https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs

On these pages it is mentioned that VERSION and MODULE are to be passed to the service while starting the Web Server. For the deployments done outside of GKE and App Engine, how to find the version?

The docs on the links above says

> VERSION is the app version (e.g., the build ID). The GCP Console displays the running app as MODULE - VERSION. Examples: v1.0, build_147, or v20160520.

But not sure where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick any names that makes sense to you for MODULE and VERSION.  They will appear in as "MODULE - VERSION" in the app selector on the Debug page.

Comment: Thanks Erez, I was guessing I had to match the MODULE and VERSION as per my project name in Google Cloud console which is clearly not the case. Thank you for your help.